Fixed shortcode download button for all digital product WooCommerce
I'm using woocommerce and have "virtual" and "downloadable" products. I want to create a shortcode to display a "Download" button for these products. Because there are so many products, I want to have a fixed shortcode to use for all products, not shortcode like [download id="123"].
I tried using this code and use [download_button] in short descreption but it doesn't work
function download_button_shortcode( $atts ) {
    global $product;
    $download_files = $product->get_downloads();
    $download_url = isset( $download_files[0]['file'] ) ? $download_files[0]['file'] : '';
    $button = '<a href="' . esc_url( $download_url ) . '" class="button">Download</a>';
    return $button;
}

add_shortcode( 'download_button', 'download_button_shortcode' );


function download_button_shortcode($atts) {
    global $product;
    $download_files = $product->get_downloads();
    if (!empty($download_files)) {
        foreach ($download_files as $key => $download_file) {
            $download_url = $download_file->get_file();
            $button = '<a href="' . esc_url($download_url) . '" class="button">Download</a>';
            return $button;
        }
    }
}

add_shortcode('download_button', 'download_button_shortcode');

Use the shortcode [download_button]

Works perfectly. Can you add a countdown time before downloading?
